# RATS Dyna Blacklist

Tags: email, dns, ip, spam-prevention, blacklist

I have checked my IP in [SpamRATS](http://spamrats.com) and the result is the following:

Standards Compliance

> Does IP Address resolve to a reverse hostname... Passed!
>
> Does IP Address comply with reverse hostname naming convention... Passed!

List Status

> RATS-Dyna - On the list. Worst Offender Alert
>
> RATS-NoPtr - Not on the list
>
> RATS-Spam - Not on the list

I have tried to do the suggestion in their removal page but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions on how can I remove the IP in the list and what can I do so that I won't be listed again.

Answer (score 0):

The Worst Offender list means that the entire class C of your IP address has been identified as an issue.  The owner of the IP addresses have to appeal with RATS.  There is nothing you can do to from the normal removal form.